# Does anyone have any feedback on using Psyco in a wsgi application?

Tags: python, wsgi

Have you tried Psyco in a wsgi application (custom, Pylons, Django...)?

What does your set up look like?

Did you get measurable results?

Comment: The one time I tried to use Psyco with Django it broke stuff.

Comment: Would love to hear a similar answer for Unladen Swallow as well.

Comment: Seems that nobody really did that. Isn't it time to explore :-) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question you should ask is not did you get measurable results, but does it make your site noticeably faster?  Most web applications are not CPU bound, so even if JIT makes them faster, you probably weren't fully utilizing your processor to begin with.

It has been a very long time since I played with psyco, but order to get measurable results I would have to simulate thousands of concurrent requests, an unrealistic situation for the average web site.

Keep in mind that psyco is not compatible with 64-bit python.  The average website doesn't need more than 4gb of ram, but think that ram is generally of more value than CPU cycles.

Answer (score 1):

Psyco is dead -- its successor is called PyPy. You are unlikely to get any speed increase with an I/O bound application however.

Comment: Wrong. Psyco is a lib you can apply to any Python program. It works with CPython. PyPy requires you to change your entire virtual machine. -1

Comment: Psyco is still dead. I hasn't been developed for a long time, and it also does not support 64-bit Python. I would advise against using it.